# Delete item in RecycleView with SelectionTracker

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I am implementing a SelectionTracker. In each item of my RecyclerView, I have an imageview with an OnClickListener to delete. My OnClickListener to delete is not triggered when the state of the SelectionTracker item is selected.

[image]

1. My SelectionTracker Builder:

   ```
   SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder(
       "macro-item-selection-tracker",
       mRecyclerView,
       new MacroItemRecyclerViewAdapter.PositionKeyProvider(mMacroItemsAdapter),
       new MacroItemDetailsLookup(mRecyclerView),
       StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
       .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything())
       .build();
   ```
2. Delete Click Listener:

   ```
   public class DeleteMacroItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             MacroItemViewHolderAction actions = getViewHolderActionSafety(view);
             actions.handleClickDeleteMacroItem(mMacroItem);
         }
   }
   ```
3. inSelectionHotspot for identify click on area image remove:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean inSelectionHotspot(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
        Rect rect = new Rect();
        mDeleteMacroItem.getDrawingRect(rect);
        int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
        mDeleteMacroItem.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
        if (((e.getRawX() > locationOnScreen[0] && (e.getRawX() < locationOnScreen[0] + mDeleteMacroItem.getWidth())))
                           && (e.getRawY() > locationOnScreen[1] && (e.getRawY() < locationOnScreen[1] + mDeleteMacroItem.getHeight()))) {
               return false;
         } else {
               return true;
         }
   //     return !rect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add an **observer** to your selection tracker.

Like this :

```
selectionTracker?.addObserver(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>(){
    override fun onSelectionChanged() {
        super.onSelectionChanged()
        //onClick for that ImageView
    }
})
```